# how to select child's number of a parent?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table that has child and parent and pid for parent is 0 and for child is id of parent. I want to select parent with number of child of that parent.

my model:

```
    function parent_child()
    {


      $row1 =
            "SELECT tbl_test.ID,tbl_user.Name,tbl_user.FamilyName,
 tbl_test.Name
 from tbl_test,tbl_user
               WHERE  tbl_user.UID=tbl_test.UserID
               AND tbl_test.PID=0
               AND  tbl_test.Status=0
               ";
      $parent=$this->db->query($row1)->result();
        foreach ($parent as $row)
        {
            $row1  =
            "SELECT COUNT(ID)
               from tbl_test
               WHERE tbl_test.PID IN $row->ID ";
            $parent['childcount']=$this->db->query($row1)->result();

            return $parent;
        }
```

my controller:

```
public function parent_child()
    {


        $this->load->model('test');
        $temp=$this->test->parent_child();
        $output= json_encode($temp);

        die($output);

    }
```

I want this output

```
{
    "parent": {
    "ID": "2",    
    "childcount": 3

}
  }
```

Comment: how can I use foreach with key value for this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
public function parent_child()
{       

    $st=$this->db->select('SELECT tbl_test.ID, tbl_test.Name, tbl_user.Name, tbl_user.FamilyName from
                          tbl_test
                          JOIN
                          tbl_user on tbl_user.UID=tbl_test.UserID
                          WHERE
                          tbl_test.PID=0 AND 
                          tbl_test.Status=0')->result_array();
    if(count($st)>0)
    {
        for($i=0;$i<count($st);$i++)
        {
            $rows=$this->db->select('*')->from('tbl_test')->WHERE('PID',$st[$i]['id'])->get()->result_array();
            $st[$i]['childcount']=count($rows);
        }
        return $st;
    }
    else
    {
        return array();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Codeigniter Query Bulider

```
$this->db->select('tbl_test.ID');
$this->db->from('tbl_test');
$this->db->join('tbl_user', 'tbl_user.PID = tbl_test.ID');
$this->db->where('tbl_test.Status', '0');
$result = $this->db->count_all_results();

return $result;
```